# SQL Server chooses worse query plan for a query on production

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have a join that was running ok for the last few years on production with no issues. It started having performance issues in the last few weeks and the database cpu shot up to 90% from the usual 30-40%.

My DBA says the query plan for this query got changed to  a worse query plan (generates query plan with index scan costing 98%)

I am not sure why SQL Server would switch the query plan and if so why switch to a worse plan than what it was using before.

In any case how do I force SQL Server to use the most optimal query plan all the time?

Comment: Parameter sniffing probably try with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` , check [Plan Guides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx), and update STATISTICS

Comment: Can you show the query ? maybe there is something in the query that is causing it?

Comment: I would update the statistics and try the query again.  From how I understand SQL Server to work, it selects the best query plan based on how many records it believes it will retrieve, and picks the least expensive plan.  Over time, you'll have added enough records for it to not select the most efficient plan if you haven't updated the statistics.  I could very well be incorrect on this assumption though, but that's just what I've noticed.

Comment: It could be any number of things. Without the query as the absolute least this is going to be guesswork. Ideally you would provide the query, the table and index structures along with the number of rows in each table.